# Add items to drop-down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to find the correct syntax to get this working:

```
 $.get('/templates/mytemplate.html', function (template) {

    $(template).find('select').append($("<option />").val(0).text('Please select ...'));
    $.each(dashboard.myArray, function () {
        $(template).find('select').append($("<option />").val(this.Id).text(this.Text));
    });
    $('#new-items').append(template);
});
```

The template variable is just a string of html like:

```
"<form class="user-item"> 
    <select class=".sc" name="context" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="date"/>       
 <form>"
```

I've tried selecting the `select` item on name `'select[name=context]'` and using a class selector like `'.sc'` as well ... none seem to work but I've got similar code working fine elsewhere.  Very confused.

Comment: are you trying to register an event handler like `$('select[name=context]').click(...)`?

Comment: No just populate the options for the drop down selector.

Comment: "template variable" is coming from server-side ?

Comment: I guess the problems seems in select tag which is a self closing tag instead of this make it container i.e. <select class=".sc" name="context"></select>. Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `template` is a string. in your case you are creating a new jQuery wrapper for that element every time and manipulating it but that does not actually change the contents of the string in template, it just changes another in memory object

You need to create a reference to a new jQuery wrapper for template then do the dom manipulation using that reference and at the end append it to the container element

```
$.get('/templates/mytemplate.html', function (template) {
    var $template = $(template);
    $template.find('select').append($("<option />").val(0).text('Please select ...'));
    $.each(dashboard.myArray, function () {
        $template.find('select').append($("<option />").val(this.Id).text(this.Text));
    });
    $('#new-items').append($template);
});
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zme53/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zme53/)

Comment: Arun he is using the jQuery object too with $(template)

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan the problem is OP is creating a new jQuery object every time by calling `$(template)` - because template is a string

Comment: @Arun, so do you are making the same. yeah not every time but first time. My point is he is also making the jQuery object and you are also using the same approach.

Comment: @Jammer did you add `var $template = $(template)`

Comment: Got it ... interesting that I've never encountered this before.  Thanks Arun I've learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

such code will work

```
var value = 'some_value',
    text  = 'some_text';

$('#id').append($('<option value='+value+'>'+text+'</option>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason your code it's not working is you are modifying a variable but don't assign the changes to variable

```
    $(template).find('select').append($("<option />").val(0).text('Please select ...'));
```

this line never stores changes to `template`, it should be :

```
template = $(template).find('select').append($("<option />").val(0).text('Please select ...'));
```